# How to handle routes in Rails with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am learning AngularJs with rails, and I have a post controller in my application. Below are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'application#index'
  get 'posts/index'
  get 'posts/create'
  get 'posts/show'

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Below are my routes of angularjs

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.router','templates'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('AllPosts', {
            url: '/posts/index',
            templateUrl: 'posts.html'
        })
        .state('createPost', {
            url: '/posts/create',
            templateUrl: 'create.html'
        })
        .state('showPost', {
            url: '/post/show',
            templateUrl: 'show.html'
        })


});
```

But I have a confusion when I hit some request in the browser, then how these routes are going to work. What is the flow of the requests and how its going to show the correct template.

Comment: Based on your angular config they won't....your angular paths will have a hash in them. If you want to remove the hash using `html5Mode` all those routes need to return the app entry point

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is a client side only framework. The routes you set up in the uiRouter are specifying only the behaviour in the browser.

In your example, when the browser has loaded the angular app, it will implement the routing specified in javascript so that when the url in the browser is `/#/posts/index` then it will load the contents of the url `posts.html` into the div with the `ui-view` attribute. This happens without any connection to the rails routes which are only running on the http server.